# Using “So” Followed by a Noun Phrase to Express Boredom, Disgust, Tediousness, Dullness, Banality

Tags: etymology, idioms, intensifying-adverbs

In the BBC TV series *Sherlock*’s episode two from series three, “The Empty Hearse", John Watson waxes maudlin over being left out of the loop for two years regarding Sherlock’s faked death. Sherlock replies: “That is so two years ago.”

I interpret this to mean so much time has passed that the subject is old stuff and Watson is behaving like someone upset over past slights. I’m interested in the etymology of this construction. I suspect it goes back to Shakespeare’s days.

Comment: Why would you suspect this usage (so + multiword adverbial construction) goes back to Shakespeare?

Comment: I think this usage is relatively interesting - to all intents and purposes, it's something that didn't exist when I first learnt English, and even today it still has overtones of "American teenager slang" to me. I wonder if the (currently ***3***) downvotes are from people who take issue with OP's particular focus on "datedness, banality" contexts. Or perhaps the fact that he suspected it was a very old usage, but that seems an even less sensible reason to downvote.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think we can really say OP's specific usage goes back to Shakespeare. The relevant OED entry (in "Draft Additions, Dec 2005") is...

> slang (chiefly U.S.). As an intensifier, forming nonstandard grammatical constructions. Cf. sense 14a.
>    Modifying a noun, or an adjective or adverb which **does not usually admit comparison**:
>    *extremely, characteristically.*
>
> Where definition 14 a is...
>   In affirmative clauses, tending to become a mere intensive without comparative force, and **sometimes emphasized in speaking and writing**.
>
> [emphases mine]

---

Their first citation for that "slang" usage is...

> 1923   R. Firbank Flower beneath Foot i. 16   *What can you see in her..? She's so housemaid.*

...but they point out that this *"represents an isolated use, apparently without influence on later development of the sense"*. Their *next* citation isn't until...

> 1979   ‘W. Allen’ & M. Brickman Manhattan in Four Films W. Allen (1982) 194   Yale:
>    *He's a big Bergman fan, you know. Mary: Oh, please, you know. God, you're so the opposite! I mean, you write that absolutely fabulous television show.*

---

The even more recent (and more "ungrammatical") usage directly evolved from this one is...

> **so not ——**: *emphatically not ——.*
>    First citation:
>    1997   N.Y. Mag. 25 Aug. 152/3   *Napoleons are so not fun to eat.*

Comment: The popular usage to express datedness began earlier than that last one it seems: New Yorker 19/09/1994 http://www.newyorker.com/archive/1994/09/19/1994_09_19_045_TNY_CARDS_000366218 _That’s so eighties. Like I remember when people would charge deliveries to a credit card._

Comment: @Neil: Not sure what you mean by that. My final example illustrates the "even-more-ungrammatical" *so **not** X* usage. I haven't even mentioned the fact that ***X*** is often a reference to past time (expressing "datedness"), because to my mind there's nothing syntactically significant about that *particular* referent. But obviously OED haven't found any pre-1997 instances of, for example, *"This technology is **so** not the future!"*.

Comment: Ah, I misread your last example. But it seems to me the "datedness" usage is a particular "meme" in itself, so this is just some extra info on that.

Comment: @Neil: I dunno. It seems to me [*"That's so last year"*](http://www.baekdal.com/blog/nothing-new) and similar are just reflections of a more general tendency for younger people in particular to slag off the past, establish authority, wisdom, and cultural traditions, etc. Well, in fact, to slag off just about *anything* - it used to be *"That's so square!"*, but now it's *"That's so lame!"* (or my pet hate, *"That's so gay!"*).